# How to check existance of an object in DetailView class inside the ListView class?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am doing Django official tutorial and I want to improve my IndexView in a way that it returns the questions with at least one choice.

I tried to work on the get_queryset method but I couldn't succeed.

**View**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return  Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

**Model:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**Urls**

```
urlpatterns=[
    #/polls/
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    #/polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: Your `get_queryset` method is not returning anything.

Comment: Sorry, I modified it. any idea about the question?